# pandas way convert time of the day (valid datetime.time) to float variables

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time, floating-point

I have a pandas dataframe, one of a column is a Time, valid datime.time format, looks like:

```
Time
16:32:00
17:13:00
18:10:00
```

If there exist a classy pythonic way to convert this time to float variable, in the way that `16:32` will be calculated as `16+32/60` so it become `16.53`  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `time` column is already datetime then you can access the time components using [`.dt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties) accessor:

```
In [18]:
df['Time'].dt.hour + df['Time'].dt.minute/60

Out[18]:
0    16.533333
1    17.216667
2    18.166667
Name: Time, dtype: float64
```

if required then you can convert doing `df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])`